# How do I get Heroku CI to run tests when using a monorepo?

Tags: node.js, github, heroku, monorepo

I have a nodejs app in a subdirectory called `node-server` of a monorepo project.

I was able to leverage [heroku-buildpack-monorepo](https://github.com/lstoll/heroku-buildpack-monorepo) project to allow me to deploy just the node-server directory to Heroku when I directly do a push like this:

`git push heroku master`

This will run the monorepo buildpack, which will copy the subfolder to a staging directory, wipe out the entire root structure, then replace the root directory with the contents of the staging directory. Then it goes on to autodetect my nodejs buildpack and everything works great.

But now, I'm trying to set up Heroku CI to automatically detect and run my tests and stage my app when I commit directly to Github:

`git push origin mybranch`

I've set up my app.json file as follows:

```
{
  "environments": {
    "test": {
      "buildpacks": [
        {
          "url": "https://github.com/lstoll/heroku-buildpack-monorepo"
        },
        {
          "url": "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs"
        }
      ],
      "env": {
        "APP_BASE": "node-server"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that Heroku sets up a read-only file system when it stages the code for test execution, making the monorepo buildpack unusable:

```
-----> Fetching https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs buildpack...
       buildpack downloaded
-----> Monorepo app detected
rm: cannot remove '/app': Read-only file system
      FAILED to copy directory into place
```

Is there any other way to get Heroku CI to work with a monorepo such that it can detect the buildpack and execute tests in a subdirectory?

Comment: Not a solution, but perhaps a path to a solution: 1) heroku doc states that the CI will use the `test-compile` script in the buildpack during the CI phase if it's present. 2 [monorepo with shared gems](https://github.com/Bus-com/heroku-buildpack-monorepo-with-shared-gems/blob/master/bin/compile) shows a way to create the build dir within the temp folder which is writeable even on a CI server. I'll be plugging away on this today, will update here if success to be had.